# Not able to change size of JLabel in GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, layout-manager

I have a label which would display strings from "0 ft" to say "999 ft", so maximum it would take string of size 6. I'm using a grid layout so that i could place that label in a particular column where it should be. I want a background for the label too. But the problem is i cant properly set the size of background.

[image: I want to size down the black part to only the required amount which im not ablet to do]

```
    public Controller() {
    super(new GridLayout(9, 9));
    try {
        Background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "background.jpg"));
        TestImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "VTOLHorizontalLevelIndicator.png"));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Background.getWidth(null),
                Background.getHeight(null)));

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (Direction direction : Direction.values()) {
        directionMap.put(direction, false);
    }
    setKeyBindings();
    Timer timer = new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener());
    timer.start();
    int i = 3;
    int j = 11;
    JLabel[][] panelHolder = new JLabel[i][j];
    setLayout(new GridLayout(i, j));

    for (int m = 0; m <= 2; m++) {
        for (int n = 0; n <= 10; n++) {
            if (m == 1 && n == 1) {
                lblAltitude.setFont(new Font("Gotham Bold",1,12));
                lblAltitude.setToolTipText("Altitude");
                lblAltitude.setOpaque(true);
                lblAltitude.setBackground(Color.black);
                lblAltitude.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(50,25));
                add(lblAltitude);
            } else {
                panelHolder[m][n] = new JLabel(" ");
                add(panelHolder[m][n]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

the above code shows the constructor from which I'm initializing the the GridLayout and the label.
*Am I using the proper layout?* **My main concern is getting labels in right places , may not be in a grid fashion but at certain coordinates in this GUI.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GridLayout will expand all of the components to fill the panel (giving each component equal size).

Comment: Try using other layout types like `FlowLayout`, play around a bit and see what works best for you. Its hard to describe in detail what you should do because only you know exactly how you want it to look and feel.

Comment: Lets say I need to set some JLabels at certain coordinates in the above GUI, is it totally necessary to use a layout, is there any solution using which i can set the locations of the labesl? 
(forgive me if i asked any dumb question above, im a noob with these layouts and swing stuff, so go easy on me)

Comment: You can definitely use absolute positioning, but keep in mind that when you, or your user, resize the window, the components may become hidden or blocked. Try to use layouts.

Comment: i have disabled resizing. so that shouldnt be a problem.

Comment: If that's the case, you should be okay with absolute positioning. The nice thing about GUI's is that it is case to case. There isn't necessarily a "right" way to do something. I think if you switch between computers and operating systems, you might notice a difference. But it seems like for your case, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @ Recursed I'm doing this project to learn more about GUI's. I know that Layouts are Important, but as of now, i would try absolute positioning. will go into layouts once i get the basics right :) thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem! GUI stuff can be frustrating, especially when first starting out. But you are definitely going about it in a good way, don't try to bite off more than you can chew! :)

Comment: yeah! will take care of that :)